# Merge o solapar capas en Photoshop

Tags: diseño

Tengo la siguiente pregunta o situación: tengo un PSD que tiene mas de 100 hojas escaneadas, tengo una capa superior en la cual le hice un marco para que no se vean las orillas de las hojas escaneadas. Ahora, la pregunta es como puedo hacer que la capa del marco de solape o se haga merge con todas otras capas para luego hacer una exportación de las 100 capas y que todas tengan el marco?

Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Espero que te pueda servir ... creas una carpeta donde quieras, te recomiendo el escritorio para que lo puedas visualizar rapido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

luego aperturas tu archivo de Photoshop el PSD con tu 100 capas escaneadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego la exportas todas las capas como archivo independiente en la carpeta que creaste anteriormente utilizando, Archivo / Secuencia de Comandos / Exportar Capas a archivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de tener todas las imagenes en una carpeta por separado , crearas en photoshop una acción.  Ventana / Acciones o [F9]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y la das la opción grabar, realizaras todo lo que vas hacer con una sola imagen, para que luego se realice por lote previo a ello tienes que finalizar la grabación y cerrar todas las imágenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se procesara hacer toda la combinación.

Esto lo realice sin problemas con photoshop 6.0
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te sirva ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos ....